# Shaping Container using Bezier Curve in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Up to this point, I wasn't aware that we could make shapes of our choices in Flutter and hence I'm totally new to this. I would like to shape my container to resemble the below design but I am totally short of ideas as to how this can be done. I did a bit of reading to find out about the concepts of the Bezier Curve but upon trying to apply that knowledge to the container below, I ended up getting something pretty horrendous. The screenshots and the code are as follows:

[image]

This is what I ended up getting:

[image]

```
class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  ProfilePageState createState() => ProfilePageState();
}

class ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: height * 1,
        width: width * 1,
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                ClipPath(
                  clipper: CurvedAppBar(),
                  child: Container(
                    height: height * 0.2,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo-with-bg.png'))
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class CurvedAppBar extends CustomClipper<Path> {
      @override
      Path getClip(Size size) {
        var path = Path();
        path.lineTo(0, size.height);
        var firstStart = Offset(size.width / 5, size.height);
        var firstEnd = Offset(size.width / 2.25, size.height - 50);
        path.quadraticBezierTo(
            firstStart.dx, firstEnd.dy, firstEnd.dx, firstEnd.dy);
    
        var secondStart =
            Offset(size.width - (size.width / 3.24), size.height - 105);
        var secondEnd = Offset(size.width, size.height - 10);
        path.quadraticBezierTo(
            secondStart.dx, secondStart.dy, secondEnd.dx, secondEnd.dy);
        path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    
        path.close();
        return path;
      }
    
      @override
      bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
        // TODO: implement shouldReclip
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Any ideas how this can be shaped?

Comment: There is an awesome web app that let's you draw your shape and it generates the code for you, it's a good starting point https://shapemaker.web.app/#/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: ClipPath(
              clipper: Clipp(),
              child: Container(
                width: 500,
                height: 500,
                color: Colors.pink,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Clipp extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(150, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(120, 150, 0, 150);
    path.lineTo(0, 380);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 4, size.height, size.width, 270);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

The output:
[image]

Edit: To make it dynamic, try this:

```
class Clipp extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    double firstFactor = size.width / 3.3333;
    double secondFactor = size.height / 2;
    double thirdFactor = size.width / 4.166;
    double fourthFactor = size.height / 1.4285;
    path.moveTo(firstFactor, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(thirdFactor, firstFactor, 0, firstFactor);
    path.lineTo(0, fourthFactor);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      size.width / 3,
      size.height,
      size.width,
      secondFactor,
    );
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Comment: This isn't very helpful. There shouldn't be any grey area inside the Container. Also, when I try checking with your code, all I see is that curved grey part inside the Container with no actual curve in the container itself. Is there any way I can create the curves in accordance with the dynamic height set it in the widget? If you run your eyes through the code I've written for the container you'll see the what I mean

Comment: Hey @coolhack7 I curve wasn't cut through the grey part, I only put the color there to show the curves clearly, You can simply remove the top container (With the grey color) to see that. To make it dynamic, I've added an edit, please check it.